# IllegalArgumentException in filtering ListView

Tags: android

I am using this code to filter my listview:

```
Cursor fetchCountriesByName(String inputText) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;

    if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {

        String[] columns = new String[] {DBHelper.ID,DBHelper.FNAME,DBHelper.LNAME,DBHelper.ADDRESS };
        cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    else {

        cursor = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {DBHelper.ID,
                        DBHelper.FNAME,DBHelper.LNAME},DBHelper.ADDRESS+ " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
                null, null, null, null);



    }
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;

}
```

I got an error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'patient_address' does not exist

But the column names are same. There is a column called `patient_address` 
What's the reason of this error? Please guide.

Comment: Did you add the `patient_addres` column after first starting the app? Then you need to uninstall or clean the app at your device.

Comment: if query call has DBHelper.TABLE_NAME and else one has TABLE_NAME, maybe TABLE_NAME doesnt have the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
cursor = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {DBHelper.ID,
                    DBHelper.FNAME,DBHelper.LNAME},DBHelper.ADDRESS+ " like '%?%'", new String[]{inputText },
            null, null, null, null);
```

the parameter is error.

Comment: I think you need to select the column in order to filter by it